# I'm trying to build an app using Google photos API, in which given a person's image, I can get all the images of him/her from Google photos

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

I'm a newbie and this is my first project on this topic. Google photos group the images based on faces. I want to fetch, set of all photos associated to a given person or set of photos in which the person is present. Is it possible to do this? How to go about doing this and if you could please specify a good source from where I can get better understanding of the API.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

### Try This Code

### call onAuthPhotoApiLoad function on button click

**also include js of google **

```
var scopeApi = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata'];

function onAuthPhotoApiLoad() {
    window.gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': "Put Client ID Here",
            'scope': scopeApi,
            'immediate': false
        },
        handlePhotoApiAuthResult);
}


function handlePhotoApiAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;

               GetAllPhotoGoogleApi();
    }
}


function GetAllPhotoGoogleApi() {
       gapi.client.request({
        'path': 'https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:search',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': {
            "filters": {
                "mediaTypeFilter": {
                    "mediaTypes": ["PHOTO"]
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);     

    }, function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });
}
```